# How to set channel value with PyDMXControl?

Tags: python, dmx512

I have a DMX512 decoder with LEDs at address 1. It is connected to the PC running Ubuntu 22.04.2 via USB/RS485 dongle using FT232R chip. It works fine with QLC+ app. I would like to control it from a Python script. I'm using PyDMXControl module and this script:

```
from PyDMXControl.controllers import OpenDMXController
from PyDMXControl.profiles.Generic import Dimmer

dmx = OpenDMXController()
leds = dmx.add_fixture(Dimmer, name="LEDs", start_channel=1)
leds.set_id(1)
leds.dim(127, 5000)
```

has no effect. How do I set the channel (address) to 1, so it matches the decoder setting? Do I have to pass the device path, e.g. `/dev/ttyUSB0`, somewhere? Is there a documentation or tutorial of PyDMXControl somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

I didn't find a way to use PyDMXControl and USB/RS485 cable with FT232R chip. I successfully used PyDMX and PyDMX-Drivers-FTDI (https://github.com/JMAlego/PyDMX) with this cable, instead.